# How to only return unique values?

Tags: sql, retool

Say I have a table, and my column is account ID.
My values are:

```
1
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
```

How would I phrase my query so it only returns the value that appears once, in this case 2? Any help appreciated!

attempting crafting query based on these instrcutions with no success: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/find-all-rows-where-the-value-in-one-column-only-occurs-once

Comment: Probably this is what you are searching for: [SQL Select Distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: @hatalmasalma The OP expects only 2 as a result.  How would you accomplish that with `distinct`?

Comment: Please share your table structure for more answer options. The answer in the link you shared must work in your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS A
GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING COUNT(A.ACCOUNT_ID)=1
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a simple aggregation:

```
select Id
from t
group by Id
having count(*) = 1;
```